# edit : battery drain *MYSTERY*

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, battery-life, bugs, samsung-galaxy-grand

UPDATE 06/02/2015

i have a Galaxy Grand Duos and i constantly faced battery drain issues. after MANY ideas to what the problem could be, (even by samsung service), i decided to root the phone and flash custom ROM. Tried some, problem persisted. 
Finally i installed CM 11.0 without any apps, not even GAPPS just to narrow down what is wrong..

After some time i can tell you that there is something like a (maybe hardware related) BUG that for no apparent reason KICKS OFF and starts draining the battery (30degree slope drop in battery application) CONSTANTLY. I mean no matter what i do, if the phone is sleeping or w/e, that is the LEAST background battery consumption. Of course if i also use the device, the battery drops more vertical in the graph for that period of time.

Then, at some point, for no reason that i can spot until now, [maybe turning on and off the airplane mode, WiFi, Screen Rotation, or somth else] the BUG stops! And from that point forward (until it starts again) the battery drop is totally HORIZONTAL when I'm not using the device, as it is supposed to be! Note that this normal behavior can last for even 2-3 days.

What will be useful : Find what triggers the bug. Find a way to stop it if has triggered.

(*edit 11/2/15- i think i've narrowed it down to how i can turn off this "bug" after it kicks in. The way to do it, might be turning on and off airplane mode and WiFi for some times. The way to see if this worked, is to leave the phone at standby for some time (1-2hr) and check the battery graph. If the graph has become HORIZONTAL for that period of time, then voila i have stopped the drain)

Note #1 : please help..!

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't comment because of low reputation points, <br>
Are you sure that airplane mode is doing the damage? Have you tried putting airplane mode in morning time to check, because some apps like antiviruses scans the mobile at night. They are scheduled by default. so that may cause the drain.<br>

Comment: thanks for your reply, indeed i checked airplane more and i am not sure it is to blame. As for apps like antivirus running, my device is stripped clean of any apps just to narrow the culprit easier.

Answer (score -2):

It isn't airplane mode.... airplane mode only stops certain hardware from running, making it physically impossible for that to be the reason

You probably have a bunch of other applications running when you go to sleep. but it will always say that Android OS used the most battery, because the operating system handles everything...

try installing `cleanmaster` or some other application cleaner, it will save a lot of battery.

Comment: for that reason i have no apps running, i didnt even put gapps. i tried several roms. 
Maybe it wasnt clear(?) that this problem is from the day i bought the phone. stock android, back to factory default, installing other roms, PROBLEM STILL PERSISTS :/

in my latest rom (CM 11) the only difference and a slight HOPE is that this BUG for some reason, for some time, it DISAPPEARS!

Comment: It isn't the fricken ROM, any AOSP rom won't drain your battery.... you still a cleaner, because system apps will still drain your battery

Comment: Please read my first answer, i have this problem since i bought the phone with stock android, and still have it after resetting factory defaults (on stock). The battery drain im experiencing ISN'T NORMAL BEHAVIOR that a cleaner could make it even better, because i am some strange perfectionist. Sorry but "Cleanmaster" has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Then get a new battery.. then there is nothing wrong with your phone

Comment: already bought a new battery (even though i had my old one checked and it was fine..) just to be 100% sure it isn't a battery problem. Result : -15euro, same problem. If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to be the battery's problem, as the "battery drain bug" kicks in at some time and stays on for as long as it wants (mb 2-3 days) but when it is off i have normal battery behavior for an equal period of time.

Comment: another hint to the cause: i think i've narrowed it down to how i can turn off this "bug" after it kicks in. The way to do it, might be turning on and off airplane mode and WiFi for some times. The way to see if this worked, is to leave the phone at standby for some time (1-2hr) and check the battery graph. If the graph has become HORIZONTAL for that period of time, voila! you have stopped the drain

Comment: when you are in sleep.. the battery will always drain... you could make it drain a lot less if you had less apps running... to lower the amount of applications running, then you should use clean master... basic computing

Comment: I really tried to explain the situation but you clearly have no idea what you are talking about, and you are even trying to give advice to others. Thanks for the effort, but if your knowledge level is "advice giving", I should be a fricking moderator..

Comment: @Tax  Actually being in a similar situation (with Nexus 9 which keeps switching itself off during standby because of battery drain), - at some point I saw that cleanmaster caused most of the battery drain. After that, maximal drain is from display, although I manually switch it off. Maybe that is behind the bug - display is using power when actually switched off?

Comment: The solution to my problem turned out to be, Buy a new phone.. Anyways, back at my old device, at the battery stats the biggest battery consumer was Android OS, don't know if that helps. And with some more advanced battery consumption statistics apps, I also found out that some of the sensors were fully working 24/7. My conclusion is that I had a defective hardware-like device that Samsung service was incompetent to diagnose and fix.. (or on purpose who knows.. the phone was still under warranty)